# Reading a binary continuously changing file on Windows

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, fstream

I'm have trouble reading a changing file, during the course of the app life time.
I'm not able load changes after writing in the file, unless I stop and restart the app. It works fine on OSX, but not on Windows.

Here is the singleton class:

```
StoreManager::StoreManager() {
   // Verify that the version of the library that we linked against is
   //   // compatible with the version of the headers we compiled against.
   GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_VERIFY_VERSION;

  // file = "data.db";
  // // Read the existing data.
  input = fstream(file, ios::in | ios::binary);
  if (!input) { 
      input.close();
      cout << file << ": File not found. Creating a new file." << endl;
      fstream output(file, ios::out | ios::trunc | ios::binary);
      if (!output)
          cout << file << ": Failed to create a new file" << endl;
      else{
          appData.SerializeToOstream(&output);
          output.close();
          cout << file << ": New empty file created " << endl;
      }

      input = fstream(file, ios::in | ios::binary);
      if (!input) { 
          cout << file << ": File not found. Failed to creating a new file." << endl;
      }
  } 

  if (!appData.ParseFromIstream(&input)) {
      cerr << "Failed to parse in date storage." << endl;
  } 
}

AppData* StoreManager::getData() {
  return &appData;
}

void StoreManager::save(){
  // Write back to disk.
  fstream output(file, ios::out | ios::trunc | ios::binary);
  if (!appData.SerializeToOstream(&output)) {
     cerr << "Failed to write in date storage." << endl;
  }
  output.close();
}
```

Expected:
To be clear, When modifying the stream and then calling save(), I should see the changes applied in appData.

Actual bug(bug is on Windows only):
My data stays the same until the moment I close and reopen the app. then I see the previously save changes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It appears that you are only parsing the file once (when the singleton is first created)...

Comment: Could you be more specific than "having trouble" and "not able"? What happens that shouldn't, or doesn't happen that should?

Comment: Have you considered closing and then reopening the filehandle periodically?

Comment: @MaxLanghof it should be enough, and it works great on OSX. The bug in Windows